Phantom wallet chrome extension recovery using seed phrase
I upgraded my chrome and lost my phantom wallet chrome extension. I downloaded again on the new Chrome and imported my Solana wallet using the recovery seed phrase. When the phantom wallet loaded my solana balance is zero. I had more than zero in my wallet (not disclosing the amount in this forum for privacy reasons) but definitely was not zero.
How is this possible when I used the seed recovery phrase?
Thanks
